# How to determine whether the same digits appear in two integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to do a function that determines whether the same digits appear in two integers. Do not take into account either the frequency or the order of occurrence of the digits in the numbers.

The numbers do not necessarily have the same number of digits. For example, if the numbers are 998 and 89 the function should return True.It is partly solved but I do not know how to count it if the length is different.

```
def same_digits(a: int, b: int)->bool:

    if (a == b):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Convert the numbers to strings, then convert the strings to sets of digits. If the sets are equal, return True.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: " but I do not know how to count it if the length is different." Do you know how to determine the length? Do you know how to check if two values are different? What exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: At any rate, you seem to have misunderstood the problem. Because it explicitly tells you "Do not take into account either the frequency or the order of occurrence of the digits in the numbers.", you should return a `True` result for `998` and `89` *even though* they are a different length.

Comment: Karl you are complety right, that is the idea to return TRUE even though the different lenght.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To check each digit you need to convert these number in `string-object` and then
count each digit from other number which result `0 or some finite number` and then using `all` we can check that all digit is present their or not.

Check out this code:

```
def same_digits(a: int, b: int)->bool:
    cond1 = all([str(b).count(i) for i in str(a)])
    cond2 = all([str(a).count(i) for i in str(b)])

    if cond1 and cond2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(same_digits(998, 892))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
False
```

### Method-2

Use `set` operation and `sorting` for that purpose.

```
def same_digits(a: int, b: int)->bool:
    if sorted(set(str(a))) ==  sorted(set(str(a))):
        return True
    return False


print(same_digits(998, 89))
```

Comment: Please don't do their homework for them.

Comment: Danke! it is plenty useful!

Comment: Don't listen to them Exploore X, it's not an assignment it's a from a challenge page to learn how to program and I got stuck, I'm just learning I'm not perfect like them. You are the best. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can just convert the two integers to a list and compare the two lists.

```
int1 = 98
int2 = 998

if list(str(int1)) in list(str(int2)):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)


>>>True
```